# Write Json Array and object with java

Tags: java, json

I need help creating and writing this Json structure for a file in the JAVA language and GSON technology:

```
{
  "field": {
    "test": {
      "param1": 0,
      "param2": "a",
      "param3": "b",
      "param4": "c",
      "param5": "d",
      "param6": "e",
      "param7": "f",
      "param8": "g",
      "param9": "h"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you have tried. Please also take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is! You can achieve this by simply using `JsonObject` in `Gson` as follows:

```
JsonObject testObj = new JsonObject();
testObj.addProperty("param1", "0");
testObj.addProperty("param2", "a");
testObj.addProperty("param3", "b");
testObj.addProperty("param4", "c");
testObj.addProperty("param5", "d");
testObj.addProperty("param6", "e");
testObj.addProperty("param7", "f");
testObj.addProperty("param8", "g");
testObj.addProperty("param9", "h");

JsonObject fieldObj = new JsonObject();
fieldObj.add("test", testObj);

JsonObject rootObj = new JsonObject();
rootObj.add("field", fieldObj);
System.out.println(rootObj.toString());
```

**Console output**

```
{"field":{"test":{"param1":"0","param2":"a","param3":"b","param4":"c","param5":"d","param6":"e","param7":"f","param8":"g","param9":"h"}}}
```

For more `Gson` usage examples, you can refer to [gson](https://www.mkyong.com/tag/gson/).